# MongoDB GUIs are broken... probably my fault?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to explore my Mongo database, but unfortunately nothing seems to be working as expected.

MongoVue will not allow me to do any manual querying: if I choose the Console, it will show up some new tab where I can supposedly write a query, but when I try to execute it nothing happens...

Then I tried RockMongo, both installing it directly to Xampp and by downloading the full environment and launching it. Both will show up and let me navigate the db, but as soon as I click on Update near to a record, it will show an empty form with the error "Notice: Undefined index: _id in D:\htdocs\rockmongo-on-windows\web\rockmongo\themes\default\views\collection\modifyRow.php on line 38". If I click to the Refresh link next to any record, the record will disappear and it will say "The record has been deleted" (only it has not).

What's wrong? Does it exist a working Mongodb gui? Or is it my fault and something is miconfigured?

**Edit**

Here is an example of a document, as provided by MongoVUE:

```
{
  "_id" : new BinData(3, "REHuTFB4mUeBAWKeY71Ttg=="),
  "name" : "Sample data",
  "type" : 0,
  "metadata" : "X=1712|Y=449",
  "fields" : [],
  "viewGroups" : [],
  "editGroups" : []
}
```

A bit more about the subject. This record was inserted using the official C# driver, using a class that had an "id" field of Guid type, marked with the [BsonId] decorator. RockMongo fails because the links generated are like this:

```
index.php?
action=collection.modifyRow&
...
id=rid_object%3A<Mongo+Binary+Data>&
...
```

Comment: I think you should check the docs of the specific gui you're trying to use and maybe tag the appropriate GUIs in this post. Rockmongo's is here: http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo

Answer (score 0):

You records do not have a "_id" field? If so, RockMongo will can not manage it.

Comment: They do have the _id field... but it is in Guid format... and I start thinking that no sane GUI will handle that...

Comment: Please give me a "document" example, i will has a try on my MongoDB.

Comment: thanks for your intrest, I have edited the answer with a single object. If you need anything more please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Try MongoBooster. Essential MongoDB Admin GUI.

http://mongobooster.com

I have test with your data. It works fine.

Disclaimer, I am one of the developers of MongoBooster